# viewpager inside page button

Tags: java, android

**i am trying to create a menu list witch i use viewpager and i want to add a button inside every page of viewpager and intent it with new activity how this possible to make?**

this is one of my page in viewpager

```html
public class meat_adobo extends Fragment{

int price= 70;
String name="classic chicken adobo";

MDB mdb;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(container==null){
        return null;
    }
    return(RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.meat_adobo,container,false);
}
}
```

and this is my view pager

```html
public class menu_meat_viewer extends FragmentActivity{

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meat_viewer);


    initialisePaging();
}

private void initialisePaging(){

    List<Fragment> fragments=new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, meat_adobo.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, meat_bbqpork.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, meat_tlshrmp.class.getName()));

    mPagerAdapter=new menu_meat_viewer_adapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.meat_view);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}



}
```

Comment: please can you add logcat error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method "onCreateView" of class "meat_adobo" must return the view which has been inflated and the button of this view implements OnClickListener.In your code, the method onCreateView returns a new view that even it has been inflated,but the button not implements the OnClickListener.Just return the view that has been inflated before...

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {


    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.meat_adobo, container, false);
    Button cca = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cca);

    cca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: im so sorry guys i didnt notice i post the new codes cos im trying to experiment somoething i will edit my post kindly plss help me

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, pop_up.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

try this

Comment: im so sorry guys i didnt notice i post the new codes cos im trying to experiment somoething i will edit my post kindly plss help me